# How can I deploy custom config files to an Identity Server container?

Tags: identity-server, federated-authentication, container

We'd like to enable the `Sitecore Federated Authentication` on Sitecore 10.2 with containers. I've updated the `ClientId`, `TenantId`, `claim transfermations`, etc... in different xml files. But I don't know how to deploy those files into the Identity Server container.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to build a custom Sitecore image for the Identity Server: https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/102/developer-tools/building-custom-sitecore-images.html

You need a project with your custom files that you can build in your solution Dockerfile (with msbuild) just like the platform build which is probably already there.

Then you need to change the Dockerfile for the ID to copy the files from that artifact (and change the docker-compose-override to pass the necessary arguments). This ID Dockerfile could be something like:

```
# escape=`

ARG PARENT_IMAGE
ARG SOLUTION_IMAGE

FROM ${SOLUTION_IMAGE} as solution
FROM ${PARENT_IMAGE}
SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]
WORKDIR C:\Identity
# Copy identity artifacts
COPY --from=solution /artifacts/identity/ ./
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Sitecore.IdentityServer.Host.dll"]
```

Comment: Thanks for the information. But I only got 2 xml files to deploy. Do I still need to create a project and execute the build? Can I just "copy" those 2 files while the IS container starts?

Comment: No, you should really do this the right way. It's really not that much work. You can copy those files but that is just crappy and not maintainable.

Comment: thanks for that. Much appreciated!