# How do I add a transform to the web.config for the Identity server with a container setup?

Tags: docker, identity-server

How do I add custom headers to the Identity server? I am using `sxp/sitecore-id6:10.2.0-ltsc2019` image for the identity server. The `Invoke-XdtTransform.ps1` we use on CM does not work as the id image does not have PowerShell. Is there any way I can add a transform to the `web.config` file on the identity service?

Comment: Did you check this ? https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/32091/how-can-i-deploy-custom-config-files-to-an-identity-server-container

Comment: @VikrantPunwatkar, I need to add transforms to the web.config file in the id container. I don't think I can add that in the project.

Comment: You may not need to include that to project, but can keep it in source control. And you need to trigger that logic to transform web config to desired values. Entrypoint in Docker file of Identity server can be used to do so and place modified web config in container.

Answer (score 0):

Create a file named CustomIdentityServerTransform.xml with your header changes.

Copy this file into the Identity Server image:`FROM sxp/sitecore-id6:10.2.0-ltsc2019

COPY CustomIdentityServerTransform.xml C:/inetpub/wwwroot/identityserver
 `Apply the transform during the image build:`WORKDIR C:/inetpub/wwwroot/identityserver
RUN .\TransformWebConfig.ps1 -ConfigPath 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\identityserver\web.config' -TransformFile 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\identityserver\CustomIdentityServerTransform.xml' -OutputPath 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\identityserver\web.config' `Build the Docker image:`docker build -t your-custom-identity-server-image:tag .
 `Run the container:`docker run -d -p 44001:80 your-custom-identity-server-image:tag
`